# While debugging in pycharm, how to debug only through a certain iteration of the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, debugging, pycharm

I have a `for` loop in Python in Pycharm IDE. I have 20 iterations of the `for` loop. However, the bug seems to be coming from the dataset looped during the 18th iteration. Is it possible to skip the first 17 values of the for loop, and solely jump to debug the 18th iteration?

Currently, I have been going through all 17 iterations to reach the 18th. The logic encompassed in the `for` loop is quite intricate and long. Hence, every cycle of debug through each iteration takes a very long.

Is there some way to skip to the desired iteration in Pycharm without going in in-depth debugging of the previous iterations?

Answer (score 5):

Breakpoint could have a condition. When the condition evaluates to `True` debugger stops otherwise skips it. See the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
for x in range(20):
    if x == 17:
        print 'hello'
    ... do stuff ...
```

Then in PyCharm, mark the `print` line as a breakpoint.

Comment: evaluating the condition on breakpoint consider to be nicest way.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a break point with a condition (i == 17 [right click on the breakpoint to put it]) at the start of the loop.